# Unreal Engine 4 - git for assets

Tags: git, bitbucket, assets, unreal-engine4

Our really small team (just 2 friends) wants to start new project (game) in Unreal Engine 4. We want to use git (bitbucket) as source control - because of its private repos for free. Or should we try something else? For now we don't want to pay for repo.

What is good aproach to sync assets? I mean big files like for example models. It may take too much time to sync and free repos have limited storage space. Should we keep them ignored in git and sync with another tool/manualy?

(I would like to use SourceTree tool if possible - I'm used to it from other projects.)

Thanks for any advice, we are just beginners.

Comment: Thanks for downvotes, but in Help Center you can find this. Please, look at last sentence. 
`When should I vote down? 
When you see an example that has issues - you should also tell the community what's wrong, so it can be fixed. `

Comment: You're probably receiving downvotes because you are asking multiple questions at once (SO works best with one question per question) and because many of your smaller questions are asking for tool recommendations and / or primarily opinion-based, both of which are explicitly off-topic. See the [help/on-topic]. In any case, your main question is on topic and answerable. I'll add an answer now.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git is not ideal for storing large binary assets, but many types of projects (like games) are largely made from these types of files.

One of the best solutions to this right now is the [Git LFS project](https://git-lfs.github.com/):

> Git Large File Storage (LFS) replaces large files such as audio samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git, while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise.

Atlassian [brought Git LFS to BitBucket Cloud in July, 2016](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2016/07/18/git-large-file-storage-now-in-bitbucket-cloud/). Since you mention SourceTree I'll note that it has Git LFS support built right in (see the previous link). It can also be used on the command-line.

Comment: Does it solve the problem with limited storage space in bitbucket? It's 1GB now. If I got it, then large files will be replaced by text pointer to the cloud, so I'll download/pull only those large files that I need. But all versions of these files must be stored in cloud. Am I right?

Comment: @Pyro, LFS on BitBucket cloud is in beta and not all of the documentation has been updated yet. There might also be changes to how it is offered in the future. But at this point I can't find any mention of a quota on how much LFS data you can store. [This page of LFS limitations](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/current-limitations-for-git-lfs-with-bitbucket-828781638.html) makes no mention of it. As far as I know, LFS-stored files should not contribute towards your regular repository limits. I encourage you to contact their support if you have further questions about their offering.

Comment: Thank you, again. I'll contact them and let you know.

Comment: we somehow missed it on their webpage. Storage limitations are [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/storage-policy-for-git-lfs-beta-with-bitbucket-828781648.html)

So your answer does not solve this limited storage space problem. Do you know about another aproach for large files?

Comment: Good find. If you want to use a cloud service I don't think you'll find _any_ without some kind of storage quota. IMO Git LFS is the right approach for large files today. GitLab's hosted service is also free for private repositories, [supports LFS](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/11/23/announcing-git-lfs-support-in-gitlab/), and [appears to have a 10GB limit per repository (repo+LFS)](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/04/08/gitlab-dot-com-storage-limit-raised-to-10gb-per-repo/). Maybe that will suit your needs?

Comment: Looks great at first look. I'll check it. By the way - we came up with some strange idea. I don't know if it will work. We will be working mostly from one apartment. Is good idea to have 2 repositories? One local on one of our computers for assets (with LFS if possible) and another one for another files (code/project files/...) in some private repo on the internet. So we can keep our code always updated and assets when we are together (as I said - we will work mostly from one apartment).

Comment: @Pyro, I think that sounds overly complicated. You'll still need some way to coordinate file changes between your two machines. I would just use Git LFS if I were in your position.

Comment: @Pyro, I'm curious how you decide to handle this. Was it much different from what I suggested here?

Comment: looks like we will use your suggestion - gitlab. 10GB should be enough.